# Insert initial items to Core Data in Swift

Tags: swift, core-data

I'm new to Swift developing. I made tableView with 16 rows - there are names and prices of every items.

When the user clicks on a row, a new tableView (with static cell) is shown. The user can edit price (I only need price to be mutable) and save it. Then, the original tableView with the new price is shown.

BUT when I stop and load app again there is the original prices.

I found out that I have to use Core Data to storage data permanently. BUT I need the database to be filled with these 16 rows (with the first load after installing) and then let user to change price permanently (or until change it again).

It is possible?  And how? Should I use Core Data or is there an easier option?

Comment: If you're new to Swift, I'd recommend you to take a look at Realm (http://realm.io) or use `NSKeyedArchiver` and save to documents folder. CoreData is too complex for something as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much everything suggested to you so far is more complex than it needs to be. You're talking about local data, and a very small amount of it.

The simplest option is to use a plist.

Xcode can help if you create a new file, select `Resource` as the type and then `Property List`. Once created it'll contain a dictionary by default, but you can convert that to an array. Add your data, so you have an array of dictionaries with your values for price etc.

Now, this file will be part of the bundle when you run the app, so you can't edit it. You should copy the file by finding it with `NSBundle` and copying it with `NSFileManager` into the documents folder.

Once it's there you can use `NSArray init?(contentsOfFile path: String)` to load the data. Use `mutableCopy` to create a version you can edit. You can use this array to drive your table view and you can edit the values it contains. Note that with this simple technique the dictionaries in the array will be immutable, so you're probably better off using `NSPropertyListSerialization class func propertyListWithData(_ data: NSData, options opt: NSPropertyListReadOptions, format format: UnsafeMutablePointer<NSPropertyListFormat>) throws -> AnyObject`  with an option of `MutableContainersAndLeaves` instead.

Once you've edited the array contents you can write it back to disk for next run (with `class func dataWithPropertyList(_ plist: AnyObject, format format: NSPropertyListFormat, options opt: NSPropertyListWriteOptions) throws -> NSData`)

Comment: Hi and thank you very much. I didn't know anythink about plist. I found and followed this tutorial: [link] (http://rebeloper.com/read-write-plist-file-swift/) and I have the last (I hope :)) question. Now I have opposite problem. When I change value of price I can't see the change immediately (like before). I can see it after I click to another view and then back again (or shut and load app again). I'm going back (from changing view to list table view) with segue to exit calling action `tableView.reloadData()`. Even `viewWillApear` is not helping. Thank you and sorry for my Eng.

Comment: your english is great. so i'd have my editing / detail view controller send the change back to the view that presented it via a delegate. the main view will then deal with modifying the array, saving it and updating the table view